# Is protractor got deprecated in angular 12?

Tags: angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpEN0.png)

There is no e2e folder after creating angular project - v12

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% depracated, angular team need to think about the future of it. You can read more in this blog:

https://blog.angular.io/angular-v12-is-now-available-32ed51fbfd49